# TemplateDoesNotExist: dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js - occurs when I run collectstatic

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I have installed Dajax and Dajaxice - and have them running fine on my local environment.  However, on my test server I get the following error now when I try to use manage.py collectstatic:
TemplateDoesNotExist: dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js

My settings.py file contains the following:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
# 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'dajaxice',
'dajax',
)

DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX = "dajaxice"
```

My urls.py file contains the following:

```
dajaxice_autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('', url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),)
```

Any idea why this might be happening - or how I might stop it happening?

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Comment: your url patterns do not seem right to me

Comment: Really?  Could you suggest what the problem might be?